# Five digit password whose digits are all among $\{0,2,3,5,7\}$

Tags: probability

A password of computer used five digits where they are from 0 and 9. What is the probability that the digits of the password  are all among $\{0,2,3,5,7\}$?

**Edit:**

I tried this way but not sure is it correct or not.

Number available 0 to 9 .

total = 10 numbers .

The code is of 5 numbers .

first number can be selected in 10c1 ways .

Since the numbers are not unique and repetition is allowed we can select the second number in 10c1 ways and so on .

So total possible ways in which this code can be made is (10c1)(10c1)(10c1)(10c1)(10c1).

Now the possibility of finding the code with only prime numbers and zero 
.

So total numbers to select from 0,2,3,5,7 .

Total numbers 5 .

The first number can be selected in 5c1 ways again repetition allowed so second number can be selected in 5c1 ways and so on .

So numbers of ways in which the code with odd numbers is selected is (5c1)(5c1)(5c1)(5c1)(5c1) .

Probability = (number of required outcomes )/ (total possible outcomes)

= (5c1)(5c1)(5c1)(5c1)(5c1) / (10c1)(10c1)(10c1)(10c1)(10c1)

= 1/32

Comment: Do you mean one of the five digits is a prime number and the rest are zeroes, or do you mean each digit is either zero or a prime number? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I mean each digit is either zero or a prime number

Comment: Is it 5 distinct digits, or can you have repeats?

Comment: @Zen repetition is allowed.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese See my edit section for what I tried please..

Comment: @Zen See my edit section for what I tried please..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since you want each digit to be either $0$ or a prime number, then how many desired options are there for the first digit? What about the second? The third? Fourth? Fifth? Then how many passwords are of the desired form?

Now, how many *total* options are there for the first digit? What about the second? The third? Fourth? Fifth? Then how many possible passwords are there?

What then is the probability that a given password is of the desired form?

---

**Edit**: Perfect (except you say "odd numbers" when you mean "prime or zero digits", though it doesn't alter the numerical result)! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

That way works, but if you think a bit you'll see combinations were unnecessary here, and that's not where I think Cameron was leading you. Combinations only become important when you start sampling without replacement (hence my request for clarification whether repetition was allowed).

You want every digit in the password to be in the set $\{0,2,3,5,7\}$. All possible passwords must have digits in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Therefore you have $5$ possibilities for a success out of $10$ total in each of the $5$ (independent) digits of the password, or 
$$\left(\frac{5}{10}\right)^5 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5=\frac{1}{32}.$$

A more pressing issue, however, is, who chooses a password like this? :)

Comment: short and easy.. thanks